# i want to integrate trading view library in my project but this error comes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

I am getting this error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UDFCompatibleDatafeed')
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import these two script in index.html /public folder

```
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/datafeeds/udf/dist/polyfills.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/datafeeds/udf/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i deleted my project and cloned their project and then i followed those mention steps then its run

i figured out the problem later

so in our on project i we missed two  script in index.html then it will give this error on running  so clone the project and then follow the mention step for your specific framework or library

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/datafeeds/udf/dist/polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/datafeeds/udf/dist/bundle.js"></script>
        <title>Charting Library React Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <!--
            This HTML file is a template.
            If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
            You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
            The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
            To begin the development, run `npm start`.
            To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```